# In mongodb how to select a document that has one embedded document but not another?

Tags: mongodb

Yes the title is a mouthful but its the simplest way I could succinctly describe the problem:

I have a document that looks something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5044ecf9d7954533000002"), "events" : [
        {
                "state" : 1,
                "time" : 1313882989,
        },
        {
                "time" : 1313883005,
                "state" : 0,
        }
]}
```

You can see that "events" is an array of embedded documents. state:1 means that the document was set to "active" at that time (seconds in UTC), and state:0 means that it was set "inactive" at that time. This essentially give me a time range of when this document was active (from 1313882989 to 1313883005)

Now Im trying to determine what documents were active at any particular time, like at 1313883013, a time that falls between the active and inactive events.

I can get something with this query:

```
db.plays.find({events:{$elemMatch:{state:1,time:{$lte:1313883013}}}})
```

It matches a complete embedded document where state=1 AND time<1313883013. This is not enough however, because I need to ensure that the document ***also does not contain*** an inactive event at or before 1313883013. So I've tried this:

```
db.plays.find({events:{$elemMatch:{state:1,time:{$lte:1313883013}},$not:{$elemMatch:{state:0,time:{$lte:1313883013}}}}})
```

but to no avail. And I've tried different variations of that as well.

I hope I've made this clear enough, thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Can events have multiple 0 / 1 transitions? Or are you saying it's either [], [1] or [1, 0] as the only three options allowed for states?

Comment: state is basically a "bit flag" 0 or 1, no other options.

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be to define a time infinitely far in the future and have any active document set to that as its end time.  If you make every event into the form `{start:12345, end:999999999}` your query is then a simple test of `start < time < end`.  When the document is no longer in use you simple find the event with the max-end-time and change that time to the current time (a simple update).

Comment: are you saying that the root document would have the start and end keys? Or each embedded document? (Just in case it wasnt clear, the embedded documents are to show a history of actions, so I need to keep those)